# WSo2 APIM 1.10.0 product profiles

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

I have wso2 apim 1.10.0 running diff product profiles (manager,worker,publisher and store) in different docker containers. I also have DAS running on a diff docker container. Im trying to view the published the statistics (https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM1100/Publishing+API+Runtime+Statistics+Using+REST+Client) but I dont see anything published. I dont see any errors in the logs. When I try to look at the statistics in the publisher/store, I get a static HTML page with a message "Data Publishing enabled.Generate some traffic to see statistics". How can i debug this?

Comment: Have you enabled statistics from api-manager.xml?

Comment: Yes the instructions in the link advises us to use the admin-dashboard. But I directly made edits to the api-manager.xml.

Answer (score 0):

1) check whether you have correctly configured the   `<DASServerURL>` and `<DASRestApiURL>` in api-manager.xml(since you enabled stats from the conf file)

2) Deploy the sample `calculator API`

3) subscribe to it and generate some traffic

The publisher statistics will not be updated until a spark script(`APIM_STAT_SCRIPT`) is executed in DAS. This script is configured to run automatically from time to time.

If you still see the "`Data Publishing enabled.Generate some traffic to see statistics`" message, then login to the DAS server and execute this script manually.

Once this script is executed the stats should be updated accordingly.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have already tried these steps.  it works correctly if I dont separate the gateway manager and the worker. This is issue is only when I have the manager in one container and the worker node in another container

Comment: have you done the configurations in api-manager.xml for the worker node?

Comment: were you able to publish and generate api traffic after worker manager separation?

Comment: Yes I was able to generate the traffic.. I was also able to view the data in the DAS data explorer. But in the publisher and store when i try to view it I just get the HTML. Although it might sound strange, sometimes I get ERROR - usage:jag java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0 and some other time I get "Error occurred while Connecting to DAS REST API".  I confirmed the DAS API URL in the API manager.xml. Not sure what else could be wrong